# Need help applying Kruskal's Algorithm to an existing adjacency matrix program that uses a 2D struct to store the data

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, adjacency-matrix, kruskals-algorithm

Link to runnable program and program requirements/specs:

https://github.com/edgr-sanchez/CSCE2110-Graph

I've thus far implemented 95% of the program. Everything runs properly and has been tested using the provided test file.

The only thing that I'm having trouble implementing is Kruskal's Algorithm, and this is because I'm not quite sure how I need to use my existing data structure to pass it through Kruskal's.

**To clarify a few things:** Running Kruskal's Algorithm in this program is not supposed to make changes to the existing data, it should only calculate the minimum spanning tree and print it out.

Running the `kruskal` command on my program should output the minimum spanning tree in adjacency list format including the street name (S##) and the distance, like this:

```
NH    NK(S02,11)    NP(S03,13)
NK    NH(S02,11)    NL(S01,24)
NL    NK(S01,24)
NM    NW(S05,15)
NP    NH(S03,13)    NW(S07,12)
NW    NM(S05,15)    NP(S07,12)
```

The location where I need to implement this is in `/src/SanE_10_P3_AdjacencyMatrix.cpp` line 208.

Anyways, I'm providing my code and all this information to help you understand my code. I do not expect it to be written for me. I'd love to simply have some guidance on how to implement this using my existing struct:

```
struct {
    bool exists = false;
    std::string name = "";
    int distance = empty;
} node[MAXNODES][MAXNODES];
```

This is the current output as well as the remaining expected output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv8D4.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I want to make a note: in fact, your `node` array describes edges, not nodes. Nodes here are indexes. Anyway, I leave the name as is. I presume that your graph is undirected. Here is how Kruskal algorithm can be implemented with your structure.

Define the function:

```
 std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> kruskal() 
 {
     std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> mst; //our result
```

At the very beginning we split all the vertices to separate trees. Each tree is identified by an index. We create a lookup table `treesByVertex` for finding an index of a tree by vertex.

```
    std::map<int, std::set<int>> trees;
    std::map<int, int> treeByVertex;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXNODES; ++i)
    {
        std::set<int> tree; // a tree containing a single vertex
        tree.emplace(i); 
        trees.emplace(i, tree); //at startup, the index of a tree is equaled to the index of a vertex
        treeByVertex.emplace(i, i);
    }
```

Then we create a helper structure `edges` that will contain a list of edges with ascending distances:

```
    std::multimap<int, std::pair<int, int>> edges;
    for (int i = 1; i < MAXNODES; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            if (node[i][j].exists)
                edges.emplace(node[i][j].distance, std::make_pair(i, j));
```

Iterate over all the edges in ascending order and test if it connects two different trees. If it's true, we add this edge to `mst` and merge these two trees:

```
    for (const auto& e : edges)
    {
        int v1 = e.second.first;
        int v2 = e.second.second;
        if (treeByVertex[v1] != treeByVertex[v2]) //use our lookup table to find out if two vertexes belong to different trees
        {
            mst.emplace_back(v1, v2); //the edge is in mst
            trees[v1].insert(trees[v2].begin(), trees[v2].end()); //merge trees
            for (int v : trees[v2]) //modify lookup table after merging
                treeByVertex[v] = treeByVertex[v1];
        }
    }

    return mst;
}
```

In fact, you even don't need `trees` container here at all.

Comment: I'm also just noticed that my struct name doesn't make sense. I'll rename its soon as I get this working.  


So, I've been trying to implement the code that you've given me but I've spent the majority of the time trying to figure out what some errors mean. 


Any time that `foo.emplace(var) ` is called, it gives an error about the variable being passed into emplace. It says "Parameter type mismatch: Expression must be rvalue".


I also get an error from the compiler saying "Error: cannot initialize a new value of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'int *'.


Any ideas?

Comment: What compiler/version do you use? What arguments do you pass to it? Is it complaining on all `emplace`-es or just one?

Comment: Complaining on all `emplace`-es. I'm using Clion on OS X as my IDE, compiler is Clang. Passing `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11"` for C++11 support.

Comment: Hey, it seems that you're using an old compiler. I've replaced `emplace()` to `insert()` and `push_back()`. See here: http://goo.gl/Vz2JQz
I didn't test this algorithm on real data. So you'd better run it in the debugger and see if it works fine. I implemented it as it's described on wiki.